# Why does md5_crypt move bytes around?

Tags: md5

I looked into the code for md5_crypt the other day (yes, I know it's insecure), and I noticed that after mushing up everything with strange md5 hashes, it generates a base64 string with a strange order of bytes. You can see that either [in the FreeBSD implementation](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/462711) lines 144-155 or in [passlib](https://bitbucket.org/ecollins/passlib/src/849ab1e6b5d4ace4c727a63d4adec928d6d72c13/passlib/handlers/md5_crypt.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#md5_crypt.py-187) which calls [this function](https://bitbucket.org/ecollins/passlib/src/849ab1e6b5d4ace4c727a63d4adec928d6d72c13/passlib/utils/binary.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#binary.py-660).

Why do they do that?

Answer (score 4):

One of the candidate answers you should consider is "for no good reason."  As Provos and Mazières put it in [the bcrypt USENIX paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix99/provos/provos.pdf) (section 6.1.2):

> Some steps in the algorithm make it doubtful that the scheme was designed from a cryptographic point of view—for instance, the binary representation of the password length at some point determines which data is hashed, for every zero bit the first byte of the password and for every set bit the first byte of a previous hash computation.

That's remarking on a different step of the algorithm than you are, but I suspect it generalizes to the step you highlight as well.  Any halfway decent hash function is going to diffuse its state, and MD5 is no exception, so shuffling the bits of the MD5 output is just suspect.

PHK wrote [a history of md5crypt](http://phk.freebsd.dk/sagas/md5crypt.html) that might be of some use to help us understand his mindset at the time, although it doesn't very much go into nuts and bolts, so it doesn't particularly illuminate the step in question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the purpose of the code is to behave as a tool for generating 'secure' password hashes. I suspect that the byte ordering decision is arbitrary and does not provide any cryptographic security.

The designs of many block ciphers omit the transposition of state in the final round for the reason that it does not provide any additional security against an attacker.

The FreeBSD code lines 144-155 is as follows:

```
l = (final[ 0]<<16) | (final[ 6]<<8) | final[12];
strlcat(passwd, to64(l, 4), sizeof(passwd));
l = (final[ 1]<<16) | (final[ 7]<<8) | final[13];
strlcat(passwd, to64(l, 4), sizeof(passwd));
l = (final[ 2]<<16) | (final[ 8]<<8) | final[14];
strlcat(passwd, to64(l, 4), sizeof(passwd));
l = (final[ 3]<<16) | (final[ 9]<<8) | final[15];
strlcat(passwd, to64(l, 4), sizeof(passwd));
l = (final[ 4]<<16) | (final[10]<<8) | final[ 5];
strlcat(passwd, to64(l, 4), sizeof(passwd));
l =                    final[11]                ;
strlcat(passwd, to64(l, 2), sizeof(passwd));
```

The final string then looks a bit like:

```
final[0] || final[6] || final[12] || final[1] || final[7] || final[13] || final[2] || final[8] || final[13] || final[3] || final[9] || final[14] || final[4] || final[10] || final[14] || final[5] || final[11] || final[16]
```

Based on the following two usenix articles [Traditional crypt](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix99/full_papers/provos/provos_html/node9.html), [MD5 crypt](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix99/full_papers/provos/provos_html/node10.html) it seems that this code was intended, not as a textbook implementation of MD5 but as a workaround to American cryptographic export prohibition and as a more secure replacement for crypt.

Comment: It comes back to my question - if it doesn't add any security, why do you do that?

Comment: This code _does_ use standard MD5 as a subroutine.  Note that _hash functions_ such as MD5 were never covered by the export controls—a political decision that never made any cryptographic sense.  This absurdity [motivated the design](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/design.pdf) of a little-known stream cipher called Snuffle that was built out of a ‘hash function’, by a well-known cryptographer named Daniel, who tweaked it ten years later to make the stream cipher Snuffle 2005, better known today as Salsa20.  What happened in the intervening decade was a series of legal battles in the first crypto war.